# Publish a ERC-20 based token in a private chain

Tags: tokens, erc-20

What are the steps to follow if I want to publish a Togen generated token. Into a exchange platform. The goal is something realted to be able to buy my own token with real money, using a platform like [Changelly](https://changelly.com/)

It´s neccesary to deploy the ERC-20 inherit Token in the MainNet to be able o buy that tokens using real money?

Its posible to manage this operation inside a private chain, instead of the MainNet to not have to pay the GasPrice in ether each time that somebody buy some tokens with real money?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

With few exceptions, tokens have to be published on the mainnet to interact with the public and trade on exchanges.

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks Rob for your always complete answers